# Shower diverter ID for old home

Tags: shower, replacement, diverter

In my 1950s house water was spraying down the stem when diverted to the shower position. It's just shy of 6 inches with a long hex nut as its bonnet.  The escutcheon is threaded and attaches to the right most threads pictured.

The hot/cold are cross style metal handles with a simple metal lever for the diverter.

I'm trying to remedy the issue of water leaking/spraying down the stem.  I can't get at the back at this time, so I'm not willing to replace the back end hardware like I should for this old shower. I also saw no removable seat when looking down the pipe.

I want to replace the handles/escutcheon, but at a minimum I want to stop the leak. Any suggestions on what replacement hardware is needed?  I have no idea how to identify the brand if I needed to keep with a specific brand. I assume I just need a new stem and seat washer and the bonnet/packing nut can be reused as long as I get new packing.

[image: 6 inch shower diverter stem with 15 spline broach]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In my town there is a small, local not-big-box chain of hardware stores. One of their specialties seems to be stocking replacement parts for plumbing from the 60's (or earlier) into the 90's and beyond. Find that store in your area and go ask.

Comment: Follow @JonCuster's advice but first know your long term plan.   Don't spend hundreds of dollars on specialist parts to keep your bathroom on life support if there is a minor or major renovation on the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Take it apart.

Then make it shine.

Now use Teflon tape where appropriate, some o-rings where appropriate and some silicone where appropriate.

Good as new.

Comment: [Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#/media/File:SiliconCroda.jpg) | [Silicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone#/media/File:Caulking.jpg) That said, caulk has no business in plumbing components. Unless you meant _grease_. Maybe be more specific.